# Is it recommended to use Stream Builder for a single data fetched from a database? if so, will it highly affect the performance of my app?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

Is there any problem using StreamBuilder for a single set of data that is fetched from database in my app?

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, **no**, it is not a problem nor does it greatly effect the performance of the app.

But as always, it depends on more factors. Let for instance say you have a `ListView` with a bunch of `Card` in it. And in each `Card` you have 10 `Text`-widgets. If you now have a `StreamBuilder` for each of those `Text`-widget, and each `StreamBuilder` does separate requests to your database, and each query is timeconsuming... then yes; it is not optimal. But if it in the end will effect the performance is still hard to say. You'd have to test :) Don't optimize before you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Stream builder is to continuously get data. Even if its a single data or multiple entries if the app needs to fetch data continuously then its good to use Stream builder. Btw fetching single entry will not affect the performance of the app to a great extent. So you should be good to go with Stream builder

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html